# Git rev-parse --show-toplevel not working for worktree within WSL

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using git worktrees and want to work in `Windows 11` and `WSLv2 (Ubuntu 20)`. Have a makefile that uses `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to determine the repository root.

However, on WSL the makefile is tripped by the following behavior:

On Windows

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
 => D:/Repos/MyRepo-0718
```

When I switch to WSL

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
 => fatal: not a git repository: /mnt/d/Repos/MyRepo-0718/D:/Repos/MyRepo/.git/worktrees/MyRepo-0718
```

I have the latest versions of GIT on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Is there a way to make `--show-toplevel` produce the same output on WSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a worktree, you typically don't have a `.git` directory.  Instead, you have a `.git` file, which is called a gitlink and refers to a special directory inside the main repository.  It makes this reference via a path.

If you make this worktree on Windows, then it embeds a Windows path.  However, a Linux Git doesn't know about Windows paths, or, for that matter, WSL, since the distro is developed entirely on a Unix system with Unix paths.

You can try, very carefully, to edit the path in the `.git` file in the worktree to use a relative path, which should work.

However, in general, using an absolute path, which is the default, will not work, because a Linux Git will never accept a Windows path (since it will consider it a relative path that just happens to contain a colon) and a Windows Git will not accept a WSL path (since Git for Windows and WSL use different roots for their Unix-style paths).

You could request a relative path option on the Git list as a new feature (or send the patch yourself), but it isn't possible to do so with the tooling as it stands.